# What's the best way to split a Grails application into web service(s) and a presentation?

Tags: web-services, grails

I have a fairly conventional Grails application. It's monolithic; although it's somewhat split into plugins along functionality lines, it is built into a single war for deployment.  Due to company architectural constraints, I need to consider isolating the app's persistence into a web service (or series of web services).  What's the best approach to dividing a Grails application into a persistence service and a presentation application?

Comment: you've answered much of your own question already in the assertion that you need to consider web-services and a presentation tier :)  Are you looking for a steer more on the architecture, or the technology choices?  I'm guessing the presentation will be deployed to a DMZ and separated from the services tier by a firewall.. do you have any further architectural constraints that would materially influence an answer?

Comment: I'm looking for a Grails-centric solution.  It seems to me that the semantics already exist for the platform to help me out.  Consider two extremes: (1) you point out a "magic bullet" plugin that instantly transforms my controller, taglib, and service code to be remote-aware, and produces a web-service build for my domain classes, or (2) you explain that Grails is roundly unfit for separating presentation and persistence in this way.  Neither is sensible, of course, but in between, you might suggest a way to leverage what I have in a way that fits the Grails paradigm elegantly.

Comment: What's the rational behind firewalling the database, but allowing operations to be performed through a Web Service? Do you expect improved security? I don't see how it may improve security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an out-of-the-box solution for your problem, and I don't believe there is one. I'll just explain the solution I use and what I would consider in your case.

In my organisation, our approach is to separate our applications in a Grails back-end and a front-end in Flex. The reason is that we have many ready-to-use Flex components that would take too much time to re-implement using pure web technologies, but here's not my point.

Creating a REST back-end in Grails is quick, as views are scaffolded when appropriate, controllers are straightforward, and input validation is greatly simplified by Domain constraints.

The drawback of this split is that definition of domain objects have to be duplicated in the front-end. You might includes objects validation in the front-end or not, but if you omit them, it will have an influence on UI responsiveness (requests to the REST back-end in AJAX calls for *real-time* validation to get the errors). At the end, our application is quite cumbersome because modifying objects in the back-end implies modification in the front-end. Furthermore, we do validation in both the front-end AND the back-end, and this code is not shared, so it must stay in phase and maintained at two places.

Our applications are split in a way that's similar to two completely distinct Grails applications that would share no code. A solution that would work in your case but is not what you are looking for, for sure.

In your case, I see two viable solutions for the web front-end:

- use the [Groovy REST client library](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) to fetch and send back your domain objects directly from your controller. If needed, pack them in command objects that reflect your domain objects, so that you can share validation code with the back-end.
- create some kind of *REST GORM* that replaces Hibernate with queries to your REST web service. You could look at the [GORM for Mongo Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mongodb) as an example of how to create such a GORM replacement.

I like the last idea, it would be a useful public plug-in. It doesn't exist yet, unfortunetly.

Comment: I like your last idea, too.  I'd like the experience of mucking with GORM, and the benefit to the public could be significant if it turns out well.

Comment: Good luck with that one :)  There is no universal standard for REST API's and each must be considered on merit.  The quality varies significantly.  Unlike mapping meta-class methods to a different database back end where the integration is fixed, you would have to provide a way for the programmer to map the methods to the specific REST API she wanted to use.  Fraught with intractable complexity if it's even at all possible, I'd have thought.  Some good RESTful design considerations on apigee.com by the way, not least this one: http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design/

Answer (score 1):

Put your domain classes in a Grails plugin, and have two distinct Grails applications, one for your web front-end and one for your web service. Both access the database directly, but code for persistence is not duplicated.

Here is a [blog post](http://www.nslms.com/2010/03/10/modularizing-your-grails-application-domain-classes/) that have some more details on how to realize that.

Comment: The blog post is excellent -- I'm grateful to you for pointing me to it.  However, I wasn't explicit enough in my problem description.  Consider me *prohibited* from accessing the database directly from my application.  Instead, I must operate the web presence from an externally-facing application which does not communicate with the database, save through a web service.

Still, placing all the domain objects in a plugin is an interesting line of thought.

Comment: We keep our domain classes in a Grails plugin so that a few of our Grails apps can use the same database. It works well.